# Statement doesn't return what i need

Tags: mysql, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, dataset

Well i have a problem with a Query of SQL in my visual studio project

I have to use Datasets cant do anything else and i use thise SQL Query:

```
SELECT Bezoekers.Naam, 
Bezoekers.Voornaam, 
Bezoekers.Gemeente, 
Bezoekers.Gsm, 
Bezoekers.Email
FROM  Bezoekers 
INNER JOIN FestivalBezoekers 
ON Bezoekers.BezoekerId = FestivalBezoekers.BezoekerId
WHERE (Bezoekers.BezoekerId <> (SELECT BezoekerId
        FROM  FestivalBezoekers AS FestivalBezoekers_1
        WHERE (FestivalId = @id)))
```

The problem is it doesn't return anything when i change the <> to = it does what it has to do and show the 1 bezoeker(visitor) when i select the right id. The problem is it has to show every visitor except the one where its id is in the table FestivalBezoekers.

Table Content:

```
Festival Bezoekers

FestivalId    BezoekersId

1             2

Bezoekers
BezoekersId Naam      Voornaam Adres           Pc        Gemeente   Gsm    Email

1           Bezoeker  Fred     Freeststraat 1  3700      Tongeren   0485/123456    fred.bezoeker@mail.com

2 Metaal Peter Grasstraat 5 3500 Hasselt 0499/987654 peter.metaal@mail.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case change your query to use a `LEFT JOIN` instead like

```
SELECT Bezoekers.Naam, 
Bezoekers.Voornaam, 
Bezoekers.Gemeente, 
Bezoekers.Gsm, 
Bezoekers.Email 
FROM Bezoekers 
LEFT JOIN FestivalBezoekers 
ON Bezoekers.BezoekerId = FestivalBezoekers.BezoekerId 
WHERE FestivalBezoekers.BezoekerId IS NULL;
```

(OR) use `WHERE NOT EXISTS` like

```
SELECT Naam, 
Voornaam, 
Gemeente, 
Gsm, 
Email 
FROM Bezoekers b 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM FestivalBezoekers WHERE BezoekerId = b.BezoekerId);
```

Comment: well if i do it like you say its good but the problem is i need to give FestivalBezoekrs.FestivalId a id. The table can be expand and when i do this query SELECT Bezoekers.Naam, 
Bezoekers.Voornaam, 
Bezoekers.Gemeente, 
Bezoekers.Gsm, 
Bezoekers.Email 
FROM Bezoekers 
LEFT JOIN FestivalBezoekers 
ON Bezoekers.BezoekerId = FestivalBezoekers.BezoekerId 
WHERE (FestivalBezoekers.BezoekerId IS NULL and FestivalBezoekers.FestivalId = @id)

I still dont get any returns from query

Comment: This is the query i needed i thank you a lot Rahul

SELECT        Naam, Voornaam, Gemeente, Gsm, Email
FROM            Bezoekers AS b
WHERE        (NOT EXISTS
                             (SELECT        1 AS Expr1
                               FROM            FestivalBezoekers
                               WHERE        (BezoekerId = b.BezoekerId) AND (FestivalId = @id)))